# Matlab sending and receiving POST to php

Tags: php, matlab

I'm having difficulty in Matlab connecting to a local webserver and sending POST data to and from a simple script. (I'm new to urlread/write and webread/write and very new to PHP).

My Matlab script:

```
myURL = 'http://localhost:8000/webhook/matlabTest.php';
[s status] = urlread(myURL,'post',{'test','data'});
disp(status);
```

My PHP script:

```
<?php
$raw_text = json_encode($_POST);
echo "triggered " . $raw_text;
```

I've also tried in Matlab:

```
options = weboptions('RequestMethod','post');
[s status] = webread(myURL,'test','data',options);
disp(status);
```

I keep getting the Matlab error :

```
The server returned the message: "Connection refused" for URL, 'http://localhost:8000/webhook/matlabTest.php' (with HTTP response code 400)
```

but if I put `http://localhost:8000/webhook/matlabTest.php` in my browser it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `400` is "bad request". something about what matlab is sending is not liked by the server.

Comment: I changed the matlab to use GET and it is sending 'http://localhost:8000/webhook/matlabTest.php?test=data'.  And then modified the PHP script to $raw_text = json_encode($_GET);

Comment: is there still a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Silly really.
Port 8000 is for the netbeans internal server used for development only.
I moved the file to my Apache server on port 8080 and all works as expected.